# Two bootstrap labels change left to right no mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two bootstrap labels together. One pull-left and the other pull-right.

Please see the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="pull-left" for="inputText">label text one</label>
    <label class="pull-right col-md-pull-6" for="inputText">label text two</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="inputText" name="inputText">
          <option value="0">Text</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

What I want to do make pull-right label float left on mobile and make on top of the pull-left label.

I know this can be done with div's using push and pull but how can I achieve this with a label?

Your help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the labels, you could include a 12-column width on small screen (i.e. `col-xs-12`) and a 6-column width on medium and large screens (i.e. `col-md-6`).

This would put the labels on top of each other on small screens and next to each other on large screens.

I added a right text alignment on med and large screens (I didn't know if you needed that) using media queries.

See running sample below

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  label.col-md-6:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-left col-xs-12 col-md-6" for="inputText">label text one</label>
  <label class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-md-6" for="inputText">label text two</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="inputText" name="inputText">
    <option value="0">Text</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try placing the label in a div and float the div left like so:

`<div style = "float:left;"><label class="pull-left" for="inputText">label text one</label></div>`